# MS Excel: How to count the unique occurrences of a substring across two cells in the same row?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

For the following, I have two columns: each column has some codes in the format `xyz***` separated by commas, where `***` are numbers.

I need to **uniquely** count the occurrences of any code whose numbers start with `3` (e.g. `xyz321`, `xyz385`, etc.) in both columns `A` and `B`, while counting the multiple occurrences of the same code as only one.

The required result in column `C` should be 5 after counting `xyz333`, `xyz321`, `xyz371`, `xyz361`, `xyz385` while excluding the duplicates of `xyz321` and `xyz333`.

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **xyz321**, xyz111, xyz222, **xyz333**, **xyz371** | **xyz333**, xyz111, **xyz333**, **xyz321**, **xyz361**, xyz222, **xyz385** | 5 |

Kindly, note that the codes to look for always start with xyz as there are other codes with different letters are there and should be ignored even if they have numbers starting with 3 as I said before.

The numbers (after the first three letters) always are three digits and located after the first three letters (xyz in our case here)

The whole single code isn't always composed of six characters as I said before since letter s can be found in some codes at the end. So, if the code is composed of seven letters, always consider the first six characters and drop the seven/last one.

P.S. I work with Office365 on Windows 10

Comment: Excel version?  Windows or Mac? what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Edit***
*given your clarification that the relevant strings will always be in the format of `xyz3##`, and that you do have Windows Office 365, we merely have to change `fn` to reflect that*:

***Edit2***
*Formula changed to account for situation of no matches. In that case, the `FILTER` function returns an error which `COUNTA` would count*

```
=LET(ss,FILTERXML(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1&","&B1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>"," ",""),CHAR(160),""),"//s[not(preceding::*=.)]"),
fn,LEFT(ss,4)="xyz3",filter,FILTER(ss,fn),cnt,
COUNTA(filter),IF(OR(ISERROR(filter)),0,cnt))
```

Comment: I apologise for adding some information lately. Kindly, refer to my question update to fully understand my whole case in case your answer needs some tweaks.

Comment: It's just a matter of changing `fn` to look for `LEFT(ss,4)`

Comment: I noticed that it results in `1` if the cells are blank or the codes to look for are not available.

Comment: @Diaa I did not account for the fact that `COUNTA` will also count errors.  See the last edit.